# Is there any time limit on the records in table user_tab_modifications table?

Tags: oracle

I'm using user_tab_modifications table to monitor all my table's change in DB, but sometimes the records disappeared.

For example, I updated the data in table A, and ran the following SQL to flush the table user_tab_modifications so that I can see the latest information there.

```
exec DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO;
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS;
```

So I can see the record about table A in there.

But then I found the record about table A disappeared after about 1 minute even though I didn't do anything in Oracle.
(other records in user_tab_modifications do not change. No problems)

That's why and can I do some settings to change it (make sure the records there will not disappear)? Thank you.

Comment: check [this](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/203931/0/) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4465.htm):

> `USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS` describes modifications to all tables owned by the current user that have been modified **since the last time statistics were gathered on the tables**.

You might want to check if some stat gathering process was running in the background on the concerned table between the time when the changes were done and when you saw the stat record disappear.